# Image.fromarray results in a horizontal image

Tags: python, encoding, python-imaging-library

I have an array of 100 randomly generated values I'd like to encode into a 100px X 1px JPEG image. So I tried the following:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def toRGB(val):
    mapped = scale(val,(0, 1), (0, 255) )
    return np.array([mapped, mapped, mapped])

# for scaling random values of 0-1 to 0, 255
def scale(val, src, dst):
    """
    Scale the given value from the scale of src to the scale of dst.
    """
    return ((val - src[0]) / (src[1] - src[0])) * (dst[1] - dst[0]) + dst[0]

# create an array of random values
def createArray(length):
    randArr = np.random.rand(length)
    mapper = lambda t: scale(t, (0, 1), (0, 255))
    # mapper = lambda t: toRGB(t)
    vfunc = np.vectorize(mapper)
    return vfunc(randArr)

def main():
    arr = createArray(100)
    im = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(arr))
    if im.mode != 'L':
        im = im.convert('L')
    im.save("data.jpeg")

main()
```

However this results in a 1px X 100px image:

[image]

How do I specify that I would like to encode the values in a single strip along the **width** of the image and not the **height**?

Comment: Try and reshape the array to (1, 100). E.g., `arr = createArray(100).reshape(1, 100)`.

Comment: NB: your example code appears to be incorrect: the `length` argument is ignored, and you create a standard random array of 10000 elements.

Comment: @9769953 using ```reshape()``` as you suggested worked

Comment: You fixed your example code the wrong-way, I think, so I changed that.